# Why does "ipconfig"not work in my windows 8 elevated command prompt?

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, ipv4

Im needing to find my ipv4 address to make a server because my old one was on windows 7 then i upgraded to windows 8, which i now regret because i cant find my computers ipv4 address when i type `ipconfig` in my elevated (Run as administrator) command prompt. it comes up with the usual error when it does not understand a command
 `ipconfig is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Does anyone know why this is happening or is it just not available on windows 8? i'v seen people do it but that might just be them using a windows 8 skin.

Picture:
[image]

Comment: What you are observing is not normal nor a restriction of Windows 8.  Works for me.  You're running into something else other than a change in Windows version.

Comment: Crap, That's not the answer i wanted to hear, well if anyone knows why this is happening please post and answer.

Comment: post an image of it. ipconfig works on all of windows editons. you don't even need to run it as administrator.

Comment: Im at work at the moment, When i get home ill be sure to post a picture, let me see if i have a picture of it on my laptop. and yes i am aware that you don't need to run it as administrator.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 His/her Problem was for windows 7

Comment: It's the exact same problem and solution, the version of Windows doesn't matter in this case (the same problem/solution would have worked in Windows 2000, for example).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your path variable is missing C:\WINDOWS\system32\

If you run `C:\WINDOWS\system32\ipconfig.exe` or `%SystemRoot%\system32\ipconfig`it should work as expected

You can edit PATH variable on Windows 8 like this

- Drag the Mouse pointer to the Right bottom corner of the screen or press Win + C
- Click on the Search icon and type: Control Panel
- Click on -> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Advanced tab
- Click on Environment Variables, under System Variables, find PATH, and click on it.
- In the Edit windows, modify PATH by adding "%SystemRoot%\system32;" on the beggining of the line

Comment: i see, so is there no way i will be able to do it through the Command prompt, will i have to run the file every time i want to see my ipv4?

Comment: if you add %SystemRoot%\system32\ to PATH as described above you can run ipconfig without path prefix, also you can still run the full path "C:\WINDOWS\system32\ipconfig.exe" from command line it works the same

Answer (score 0):

This issue will occur if the  "PATH" environment variable did NOT include "C:\WINDOWS\system32"
Any executable in that folder could only be run from a cmd prompt if the command included the entire path.

Solution for this is to add "C:\WINDOWS\system32;" to the start of my PATH environment variable, like this:

```
Log in with Administrator priviledges.
Right-click "My Computer" & select "Properties."
Click "Advanced" tab.
Click "Environment Variables" button.
In the "System variables" box, scroll down to "PATH" and highlight it.
Click the "Edit" button.
In the "Variable value:" box, add to the very beginning of the text "C:\WINDOWS\system32;" without my quotation marks.
Make sure you include the semicolon.
Click OK three times.
No reboot required. If this was your problem, then ipconfig should work right away.
```